# PHP variable value not printing outside try catch

Tags: php, exception

I am trying to print variable value outside try catch code but it is not getting printed. 
following is my code

```
 $error;
 try {

  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      "description"=>"Customer",
        "source" => $token,
        "email" => $email,
      "plan" => "armorax"
          )
    );

 $payment = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
 'amount'        => $amount,
 'currency'      => 'usd',

 'description'   => $_POST['description'],
  "customer" => $customer->id

 )
 );




 } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {

   $body = $e->getJsonBody();
   $err  = $body['error'];
    $error= 'Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . "\n";
 }

 //SOme HTML CODE
  <div class="alert"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
```

$error should print an error if there is but is not printing error.

Comment: 1. `$error;` What should that do? Here this is just a NOP 2. Where do you assign a value to `$error` ? 3. `Exception ex` Missing dollar sign! 4. Where is your php end tag?

Comment: Is there an error in the `try` that would be caught in the `catch`? You only enter the `catch` portion if an exception happens.

Comment: Question updated check and see now. and when i have mentioned that it is in php then it is understood that i have <?php in my file.

Answer (score 0):

A few things. What are you doing with the line `$error;`? If you're trying to initialize the variable, just set it to null with `$error = null;`.

Secondly, Make sure you're writing your try/catch correctly.

```
try {
 //SomePhp code here
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

If it's not echoing the exception, then the try is not failing to begin with.

[PHP documentation - Try/Catch](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.catch.php)

Comment: I have updated my question, please check and reply now Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried some debugging through `echo()` or `var_dump()`? Have you made sure you're entering the `catch` portion of the code?

Comment: yes friend i did with print_r() but no success. i also tried adding global $error at initial line to define scope of variable but still it is not working.